# Convert JSON list to table where one record is a list

Tags: json, excel, powerquery

I have a JSON list with 253 entries and 7 records where the 7th record is a list with usually 2 entries.

I'm trying to convert this in Power Query to give me a table output. I've only really ever used the basic connection in Excel to do this automatically without problems.

My current error is:

> Expression.Error: We cannot convert a value of type Record to type Text.
>   Details:
>       Value=Record
>       Type=Type

[image]

I'm not sure where to go and I can't see examples for my specific situation, although I'm sure there are plenty of examples - just that I'm not good enough with this to understans

```
[
  {
    "Id": "lorum-ipsum1",
    "Description": "sitename 1",
    "Latitude": 1.0,
    "Longitude": -1.0,
    "Postcode": "AB1 2CD",
    "CountryCode": "GB",
    "Connectors": [
      {
        "Id": "lorum-ipsum1-a",
        "Number": 1,
        "Status": 1,
        "ErrorCode": "NoError",
        "ChargepointName": "GP00000",
        "Shape": 0,
        "Mode": 0,
        "Volts": 240,
        "Amps": 0,
        "Phase": 2,
        "PricingInformationUrl": "hrefhere",
        "UsageRestrictions": []
      },
      {
        "Id": "lorum-ipsum1-b",
        "Number": 2,
        "Status": 1,
        "ErrorCode": "NoError",
        "ChargepointName": "GP0000",
        "Shape": 0,
        "Mode": 0,
        "Volts": 240,
        "Amps": 0,
        "Phase": 2,
        "PricingInformationUrl": "hrefhere",
        "UsageRestrictions": []
      }
    ]
  },
   {
    "Id": "lorum-ipsum2",
    "Description": "sitename 2",
    "Latitude": 1.0,
    "Longitude": -1.0,
    "Postcode": "AB1 2CD",
    "CountryCode": "GB",
    "Connectors": [
      {
        "Id": "lorum-ipsum2-a",
        "Number": 1,
        "Status": 1,
        "ErrorCode": "NoError",
        "ChargepointName": "GP00000",
        "Shape": 0,
        "Mode": 0,
        "Volts": 240,
        "Amps": 0,
        "Phase": 2,
        "PricingInformationUrl": "hrefhere",
        "UsageRestrictions": []
      },
      {
        "Id": "lorum-ipsum2-b",
        "Number": 2,
        "Status": 1,
        "ErrorCode": "NoError",
        "ChargepointName": "GP0000",
        "Shape": 0,
        "Mode": 0,
        "Volts": 240,
        "Amps": 0,
        "Phase": 2,
        "PricingInformationUrl": "hrefhere",
        "UsageRestrictions": []
      }
    ]
  },
```

Comment: Can you show what you want the resulting table to look like?

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to use `Table.FromRecords` function to transform the JSON into a table. However, since the `Connectors` field of each record is itself a list of records, I think you will need to call it a second time.

To give you an example:

```
let
    serialised = "[{""Id"":""lorum-ipsum1"",""Description"":""sitename 1"",""Latitude"":1,""Longitude"":-1,""Postcode"":""AB1 2CD"",""CountryCode"":""GB"",""Connectors"":[{""Id"":""lorum-ipsum1-a"",""Number"":1,""Status"":1,""ErrorCode"":""NoError"",""ChargepointName"":""GP00000"",""Shape"":0,""Mode"":0,""Volts"":240,""Amps"":0,""Phase"":2,""PricingInformationUrl"":""hrefhere"",""UsageRestrictions"":[]},{""Id"":""lorum-ipsum1-b"",""Number"":2,""Status"":1,""ErrorCode"":""NoError"",""ChargepointName"":""GP0000"",""Shape"":0,""Mode"":0,""Volts"":240,""Amps"":0,""Phase"":2,""PricingInformationUrl"":""hrefhere"",""UsageRestrictions"":[]}]},{""Id"":""lorum-ipsum2"",""Description"":""sitename 2"",""Latitude"":1,""Longitude"":-1,""Postcode"":""AB1 2CD"",""CountryCode"":""GB"",""Connectors"":[{""Id"":""lorum-ipsum2-a"",""Number"":1,""Status"":1,""ErrorCode"":""NoError"",""ChargepointName"":""GP00000"",""Shape"":0,""Mode"":0,""Volts"":240,""Amps"":0,""Phase"":2,""PricingInformationUrl"":""hrefhere"",""UsageRestrictions"":[]},{""Id"":""lorum-ipsum2-b"",""Number"":2,""Status"":1,""ErrorCode"":""NoError"",""ChargepointName"":""GP0000"",""Shape"":0,""Mode"":0,""Volts"":240,""Amps"":0,""Phase"":2,""PricingInformationUrl"":""hrefhere"",""UsageRestrictions"":[]}]}]",
    deserialised = Json.Document(serialised),
    toTable = Table.FromRecords(deserialised),
    transformConnectors = Table.TransformColumns(toTable, {{"Connectors", Table.FromRecords}})
in
    transformConnectors
```

which gives me:

[image: Output table]

From there, you can explore/continue the rest of the transformation yourself (since you haven't specified what you want).

You can expand some/all nested columns inside of the `Connectors` column by either clicking the icon highlighted in the image above -- or writing any necessary `M` code.